# Application Domain isolation

Tags: c#, .net, clr

### "The isolation provided by application domains has the following benefits:

Faults in one application cannot affect other applications. Because type-safe code cannot cause memory faults, using application domains ensures that code running in one domain cannot affect other applications in the process."##
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx

The above words was got from The MSDN,

My questions are,

> 1, The "Faults" in the sentence  refer to the exception ,or something else?
>
> 2, what is The "Faults in one application cannot affect other applications" means?, 
>   Does it means if there throw an exception in one Application Domain ,that exception will not crash other Application Domains, right?
>   Can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article talks about memory isolation. Managed code can't arbitraty modify memory (without `unsafe`) unlike C/C++ thus managed code running in one AppDomain will not corrupt memory in other AppDomain. I.e. buffer overflow kind of errors are prevented by managed runtime, while easy to achieve in C/C++ like `int arr[4]; arr[-1]=2;`.

Exceptions are not scoped to AppDomain (or rather behave similar with/without AppDomains) - most exceptions will only impact code that called method that throws exception, some (i.e. StackOverflow) by default will terminate the process. If normal exception is unhandled it normally will cause process termination. Exceptions are free to cross AppDomain boundaries if code on the stack bekongs to multiple AppDomains.

Comment: thank you alexei.""you said "buffer overflow kind of errors are prevented by managed runtime" , so how managed runtime achieve that protection?

Comment: @jacky_shen, essentially runtime can verify if code does whatever it supposed to do. I.e. IL is enough to check if code either reads/writes fields of known object, if checks boundaries on every array access... If IL fails the verification (i.e. one hacked in access to random memory address) such code will fail verification at runtime and will not be JITed/executed.